# scrolling lags in emacs 23.2 with GTK

Tags: emacs, emacs23

I am using emacs 23.2 with the GTK toolkit. I built emacs from source using the following configure-params:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --without-makeinfo --without-sound
```

Which builds emacs with the following configuration:

```
  Where should the build process find the source code?    /home/****/incoming/emacs-23.2
  What operating system and machine description files should Emacs use?
        `s/gnu-linux.h' and `m/intel386.h'
  What compiler should emacs be built with?               gcc -g -O2 -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign  
  Should Emacs use the GNU version of malloc?             yes
      (Using Doug Lea's new malloc from the GNU C Library.)
  Should Emacs use a relocating allocator for buffers?    yes
  Should Emacs use mmap(2) for buffer allocation?         no
  What window system should Emacs use?                    x11
  What toolkit should Emacs use?                          GTK
  Where do we find X Windows header files?                Standard dirs
  Where do we find X Windows libraries?                   Standard dirs
  Does Emacs use -lXaw3d?                                 no
  Does Emacs use -lXpm?                                   yes
  Does Emacs use -ljpeg?                                  yes
  Does Emacs use -ltiff?                                  yes
  Does Emacs use a gif library?                           yes -lgif
  Does Emacs use -lpng?                                   yes
  Does Emacs use -lrsvg-2?                                no
  Does Emacs use -lgpm?                                   yes
  Does Emacs use -ldbus?                                  yes
  Does Emacs use -lgconf?                                 no
  Does Emacs use -lfreetype?                              yes
  Does Emacs use -lm17n-flt?                              no
  Does Emacs use -lotf?                                   yes
  Does Emacs use -lxft?                                   yes
  Does Emacs use toolkit scroll bars?                     yes
```

My OS is OpenSuSE 11.1, GTK version is 2.14.4.
When I'm scrolling within files of a common size (about 1000 lines) holding the up/down-keys, emacs almost hangs and produces about 50% CPU-load. I use the following plugins:

- ido
- linum
- tabbar
- auto-complete-config

Starting emacs with `-q` fixes the problem, but then I don't have any plugins. I can't figure out, which part of my `.emacs` is responsible for this behaviour.
Here's an excerpt of my `.emacs`-file:

```
(require 'ido)
(ido-mode 1)

(require 'linum)
(global-linum-mode 1)

(require 'tabbar)
(tabbar-mode 1)
(tabbar-local-mode 0)
(tabbar-mwheel-mode 0)
(setq tabbar-buffer-groups-function
      (lambda ()
        (list "All")))
(global-set-key [M-left] 'tabbar-backward)
(global-set-key [M-right] 'tabbar-forward)

;; hide the toolbar (gtk etc.)
(tool-bar-mode -1)

;; Mouse scrolling enhancements
(setq mouse-wheel-progressive-speed nil)
(setq mouse-wheel-scroll-amount '(5 ((shift) . 5) ((control) . nil)))

;; Smart-HOME
(defun smart-beginning-of-line ()
  "Forces the cursor to jump to the first none whitespace char of the current line when pressing HOME"
  (interactive)
  (let ((oldpos (point)))
    (back-to-indentation)
    (and (= oldpos (point))
         (beginning-of-line))))
(put 'smart-beginning-of-line 'CUA 'move)
(global-set-key [home] 'smart-beginning-of-line)

(custom-set-variables
  ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(column-number-mode t)
 '(cua-mode t nil (cua-base))
 '(custom-buffer-indent 4)
 '(delete-selection-mode nil)
 '(display-time-24hr-format t)
 '(display-time-day-and-date 1)
 '(display-time-mode t)
 '(global-font-lock-mode t nil (font-lock))
 '(inhibit-startup-buffer-menu t)
 '(inhibit-startup-screen t)
 '(pc-select-meta-moves-sexps t)
 '(pc-select-selection-keys-only t)
 '(pc-selection-mode t nil (pc-select))
 '(scroll-bar-mode (quote right))
 '(show-paren-mode t)
 '(standard-indent 4)
 '(uniquify-buffer-name-style (quote forward) nil (uniquify)))

(setq-default tab-width 4)
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)
(setq c-basic-offset 4)

;; Highlighting of the current line
(global-hl-line-mode 1)
(set-face-background 'hl-line "#E8F2FE")

(defalias 'yes-or-no-p 'y-or-n-p)
(display-time)
(set-language-environment "Latin-1")

;; Change cursor color according to mode
(setq djcb-read-only-color       "gray")
;; valid values are t, nil, box, hollow, bar, (bar . WIDTH), hbar,
;; (hbar. HEIGHT); see the docs for set-cursor-type
(setq djcb-read-only-cursor-type 'hbar)
(setq djcb-overwrite-color       "red")
(setq djcb-overwrite-cursor-type 'box)
(setq djcb-normal-color          "black")
(setq djcb-normal-cursor-type    'bar)

(defun djcb-set-cursor-according-to-mode ()
  "change cursor color and type according to some minor modes."
  (cond
    (buffer-read-only
      (set-cursor-color djcb-read-only-color)
      (setq cursor-type djcb-read-only-cursor-type))
    (overwrite-mode
      (set-cursor-color djcb-overwrite-color)
      (setq cursor-type djcb-overwrite-cursor-type))
    (t 
      (set-cursor-color djcb-normal-color)
      (setq cursor-type djcb-normal-cursor-type))))
(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'djcb-set-cursor-according-to-mode)

(define-key global-map '[C-right] 'forward-sexp)
(define-key global-map '[C-left] 'backward-sexp)
(define-key global-map '[s-left] 'windmove-left)
(define-key global-map '[s-right] 'windmove-right)
(define-key global-map '[s-up] 'windmove-up)
(define-key global-map '[s-down] 'windmove-down)
(define-key global-map '[S-down-mouse-1] 'mouse-stay-and-copy)
(define-key global-map '[C-M-S-down-mouse-1] 'mouse-stay-and-swap)
(define-key global-map '[S-mouse-2] 'mouse-yank-and-kill)
(define-key global-map '[C-S-down-mouse-1] 'mouse-stay-and-kill)
(define-key global-map "\C-a" 'mark-whole-buffer)

(custom-set-faces
  ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :background "#f7f9fa" :foreground "#191919" :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 98 :width normal :foundry "unknown" :family "DejaVu Sans Mono"))))
 '(font-lock-builtin-face ((((class color) (min-colors 88) (background light)) (:foreground "#642880" :weight bold))))
 '(font-lock-comment-face ((((class color) (min-colors 88) (background light)) (:foreground "#3f7f5f"))))
 '(font-lock-constant-face ((((class color) (min-colors 88) (background light)) (:weight bold))))
 '(font-lock-doc-face ((t (:inherit font-lock-string-face :foreground "#3f7f5f"))))
 '(font-lock-function-name-face ((((class color) (min-colors 88) (background light)) (:foreground "Black" :weight bold))))
 '(font-lock-keyword-face ((((class color) (min-colors 88) (background light)) (:foreground "#7f0055" :weight bold))))
 '(font-lock-preprocessor-face ((t (:inherit font-lock-builtin-face :foreground "#7f0055" :weight bold))))
 '(font-lock-string-face ((((class color) (min-colors 88) (background light)) (:foreground "#0000c0"))))
 '(font-lock-type-face ((((class color) (min-colors 88) (background light)) (:foreground "#7f0055" :weight bold))))
 '(font-lock-variable-name-face ((((class color) (min-colors 88) (background light)) (:foreground "Black"))))
 '(minibuffer-prompt ((t (:foreground "medium blue"))))
 '(mode-line ((t (:background "#222222" :foreground "White"))))
 '(tabbar-button ((t (:inherit tabbar-default :foreground "dark red"))))
 '(tabbar-button-highlight ((t (:inherit tabbar-default :background "white" :box (:line-width 2 :color "white")))))
 '(tabbar-default ((t (:background "gray90" :foreground "gray50" :box (:line-width 3 :color "gray90") :height 100))))
 '(tabbar-highlight ((t (:underline t))))
 '(tabbar-selected ((t (:inherit tabbar-default :foreground "blue" :weight bold))))
 '(tabbar-separator ((t nil)))
 '(tabbar-unselected ((t (:inherit tabbar-default)))))
```

Any suggestions?
Kind regards,
mefiX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks OK to me.  The fact that it runs OK with emacs -q is key, since it means you can solve the problem.

Now, I hope that someone offers you a simple diagnosis based on your files, but if not (and hey it's been 7 hours), you can always try the standard .emacs-debugging slow coach.  It's not particularly fun, but it'll work.

Chose your pleasure:

(A) Divide and Conquer

Divide your .emacs mentally into 4 parts.  Now figure out which quarter is causing your problem by making four separate trial emacs configs: the first with 1/4 of your emacs, the next with half, the next with three quarters, and the final one with everything.

```
emacs --no-site-file    # see if the problem is in your site-wide emacs init
emacs -q -l config1     # is it in the first quarter
emacs -q -l config2     # is it in the first half (i.e. the second quarter)
emacs -q -l config3     # is it in the third quarter
emads -q -l config4     # gotta be here, but test again to be sure
```

If you don't find the culprit, you can further divide.  If you suspect you have a culprit, or just like the look of this method better, try this:

(B) Check each step

load a blank emacs with `emacs -q`

visit your .emacs in a buffer

visit your 1K line file in another buffer.

use eval-last-sexp C-x C-e, or eval-region to try each section or line in your .emacs, either systematically from the beginning, or starting with any suspect function calls.

Slowly but surely, you'll smoke it out.  Sorry I can't offer you instant diagnosis.

Comment: I chose "pleasure" (B) because I already had some suspect candidates like tabbar.el and linum.el.
It turns out, that tabbar.el is the winner. But still: even a naked emacs (starting with -q) produces about 17% load when holding the up/down keys to scroll in a large file. Enabling everything except tabbar increases load up to 20-24%. Enabling tabbar then, doubles the load up to 45-50%! Whats the matter with tabbar.el? I mean: it should only display the current buffers, which in fact do not change during scrolling!? I took tabbar.el from the aquamacs site. The file says its version 2.0.

Comment: Same here: I use tabbar, but it slows Emacs down noticeably. I'd hate to have to ditch it, though, because it's so convenient. Maybe someday someone will debug tabbar's speed problem, said he hopefully.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, turning off linum mode solves problem with scroll freeze.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with emacs 24. Turned out to be tabbar-mode that slowed it down.